# R gsub everything after blank

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am stuggling to figure out how to `gsub` everything after the "blank" of the first *hour* value.

```
as.data.frame(valeur)

         valeur
1    8:01 8:15 
2  17:46 18:00 
3          <NA>
4          <NA>
5          <NA>
6          <NA>
7    8:01 8:15 
8  17:46 18:00
```

What I need is

```
     valeur
1          8:01
2         17:46
3          <NA>
4          <NA>
5          <NA>
6          <NA>
7          8:01
8         17:46
```

Any clue ?

I tried

```
 gsub("[:blank:].*$","",valeur)
```

Almost

```
valeur = c(" 8:01 8:15 ", " 17:46 18:00 ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " 8:01 8:15 ", 
" 17:46 18:00 ")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have leading/lagging spaces from the 'valeur' output.  We can remove those with `gsub`.  We match one or more space from the beginning of the string (`^\\s+`) or (`|`) space at the end of the string (`\\s+$`), replace with `''`.

```
valeur1 <- gsub('^\\s+|\\s+$', '', valeur)
```

If we need the first non-space characters, we match the space (`\\s+`) followed by non-space (`\\S+`) till the end of the string and replace with `''`.

```
sub('\\s+\\S+$', '', valeur1)
#[1] "8:01"  "17:46" NA      NA      NA      NA      "8:01"  "17:46"
```

To get the last non-space characters, use `sub` to match one or more characters that are not a space (`\\S+`) from the beginning of the string ('^') followed by one or more space (`\\s+`) and replace it with `''` to get the last non-space character.

```
sub('^\\S+\\s+', '', valeur1)
#[1] "8:15"  "18:00" NA      NA      NA      NA      "8:15"  "18:00"
```

---

The above can be done in a single step where we match zero or more space at the beginning (`^\\s*`) or (`|`) a one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by one or more non-space characters (`\\S+`), followed by zero or more space characters at the end (`\\s*$`) and replace by `''`.

```
 gsub("^\\s*|\\s+\\S+\\s*$","",valeur)
 #[1] "8:01"  "17:46" NA      NA      NA      NA      "8:01"  "17:46"
```

---

Or another option is `stri_extract_first` or `stri_extract_last` from `library(stringi)` where we match one or more non-space characters at the beginning or the end.

```
 library(stringi)
 stri_extract_first(valeur, regex='\\S+')
 #[1] "8:01"  "17:46" NA      NA      NA      NA      "8:01"  "17:46"
```

For the `last` non_space characters

```
 stri_extract_last(valeur, regex='\\S+')
 #[1] "8:15"  "18:00" NA      NA      NA      NA      "8:15"  "18:00"
```

Answer (score 2):

for the sake of contribution, just thought of :

```
substr(x = valeur, start = 2, stop = 6)
[1] "8:01 " "17:46" NA      NA      NA      NA      "8:01 " "17:46"
```